# Autogenerate code with shortcuts in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I noticed that when you type ctor then hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button, VS will automatically create a constructor skeleton for you.

I also saw in a screencast, the speaker could generate, among other things :`Console.WriteLine`, and also skeleton methods for all interface methods using keyboard shortcuts.

However, I couldn't get what keyword he was typing.

What is this feature called? and where can I see the list of keywords and the effects?

Comment: upon reading again, I think my writing was pretty confusing. I'm trying to edit it, if you have the privilege feel free to edit the sentence, too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is what you may be looking for.

Various options of how to invoke them, including via keyboard shortcuts are [listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4c5cc9b%28VS.80%29.aspx)

The above link just lists the default snippets that come with VS.

However you can also create and use your own snippets. Refer [tutorials here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for how to go about doing it

Answer (score 2):

They're called Code Snippets:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx
- http://devshaped.com/2009/01/accelerate-your-coding-with-code-snippets/